# detach and appendTo list of images

Tags: jquery

When I click on a image I can remove all the siblings and bring them back later using

```
p =$(this).siblings().detach();
```

and using this to bring them back

```
p.appendTo(".grid li");
```

but I can't get rid of both the parent and siblings on a click and also bring them back.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/41/)

Comment: http://jqapi.com/#p=detach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hc4MZ/)

```
 $('#hidden').click(function () {
     p.prependTo("body");
 });
```

Comment: with "body" being the key part of the answer

Comment: @koala_dev i'd say the key is to append/prepend to any element in the DOM or these method have no effect

Comment: Agreed, I just meant that the fact that you used prepend instead of append doesn't make a difference in this example